# WCF maxReceivedMessagesize and readerquotas

Tags: wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

What is the fundamental difference between the two? On the server side on the service, I am using readerQuotas to accomodate large string lengths (Int32.MaxValue). What is the significance of maxReceivedMessagesize then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[maxReceivedMessagesize](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128000850/http://geekswithblogs.net/niemguy/archive/2007/12/11/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-maxbuffersize-and-maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) is the total size of the message.

[readerQuotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms731325%28v=vs.110%29) are the size of parts of the message for example the length of a string in the message.

You need both of them so be set high enough for your message to go through, often the defaults will be OK.