# how to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize when calling a WCF from vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

I am using Wcf when I search for 1 day data I am getting results but if I search 30 days data I am getting below error.

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.GetMessageBuffer()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IToursGdsService.getBatchAvailability(getBatchAvailabilityRequest request)
   at ToursGdsServiceClient.IToursGdsService.getBatchAvailability(getBatchAvailabilityRequest request)

Inner Exception:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

My Service.config file has the following code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" connectionString="Server=.;Database=test;User ID=test;Password=test123"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="TourGDSService.ToursGdsService.svc" service="TourGDSService.ToursGdsService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataServiceExtension">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ToursGdsService" >
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"   maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>

        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="metadataService" type="Thinktecture.ServiceModel.Extensions.Metadata.StaticMetadataBehaviorElement, Thinktecture.ServiceModel.Extensions.Metadata, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataServiceExtension" name="TourGDSService.ToursGdsService">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="customBinding" bindingNamespace="http://giinfotech.com/app/05"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ToursGdsService"    contract="IToursGdsService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you also post the configuration file of the client application ? (I think this is the one from the service application)

Comment: Are you trying to consume http://giinfotech.com/app/05 service ? If so, the endpoint should stay in <client></client> instead of <srevices></services>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is not related to the total size of the message, but to the size of elements of the message.

Take a look at this question:
[WCF maxReceivedMessagesize and readerquotas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517234/wcf-maxreceivedmessagesize-and-readerquotas)

If this is the problem, add the following configuration:

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ToursGdsService" >
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httpTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
       <readerQuotas
          maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
```

Also, you can try adding the attributes maxReceivedMessageSize, maxBufferPoolSize and maxBufferSize on binding instead of httpTransport.

Comment: Dear Cosmin Thanks for your reply.I have added readerQuotas also in config still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Is it the same error if you move the attributes from httptransport to binding ?

Comment: Remember this or similar config code needs to be in both the server and the consuming client

Answer (score 0):

If you declare you binding in code your buffer size can be increased there.

```
BasicHttpBinding q = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
q.MaxBufferSize = 2147483646;
q.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483646;
q.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483646;
```

if not you can try doing the pool size script but i'm not sure 100% where it goes
(i would have asked in a comment but i don't have 50 rep yet )

Comment: I only used basic to demostrate you can do this with your custom one